# Centre of mass not recalculated after scaling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am spawning a prefab object at runtime (actually, in the `Start()` method of another object), and I need to apply a scaling to the object. I made a little component to handle this:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform SpawnPrefab;
  public Vector3 Scale;

    void Start () {
      var spawn = Instantiate(SpawnPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
      spawn.localScale = Vector3.Scale(spawn.localScale, Scale);
      // spawn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();  // Has no effect
    }
}
```

The pivot point of the prefab I am spawning does not coincide with the centre of mass of the object. Therefore, the rescaling means that the centre of mass location relative to the pivot will change. However, it's *not* being updated automatically, so my spawned object has unexpected physics.

I tried adding a call to `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass()` immediately after the call to `Scale()`  (the commented-out line above), but this has no effect.

However, if I put the call to `ResetCenterOfMass()` in the `Start()` method of a separate little component added to the spawned object, e.g.

```
public class COMReset : MonoBehaviour {
  void Start() {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();
  }
}
```

this *does* cause the centre of mass to be recalculated correctly. However, the spawned object appears to have already been through at least one physics update with the wrong COM by this time, and so has already acquired some unexpected momentum.

Why isn't the COM being automatically recalculated, without me having to call `ResetCenterOfMass()` explicitly? And if I must trigger it manually, can I do that immediately after the calls to `Instantiate()` and `Scale()`, rather than deferring like this?

Comment: maybe you need to wait one frame after scaling to recalculate it? make Start a coroutine and add "yield return null;" before recalculating, (that makes it wait one frame) try it out :)

Comment: @Lestat Thanks - this does result in a correct COM - however, it appears the spawned object has already been through one or more physics updates with the wrong COM by then, and so it has already aquired some unexpected momentum... In fact, I just realised that my method using the `COMReset` component also has this problem (though it seems to a lesser extent).

Comment: well, a workaround would be to freeze the object till its recalculated (only one frame)

Comment: @Lestat Yep, that works - would still love to find a solution that doesn't feel like a workaround, but great to have at least one way to handle this! Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: What if you put the Instantiate in Awake and recalculate the center of mass in Start?

Comment: I am the master of workarounds xd

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge Thanks for the suggestion! I did try this, but unfortunately it didn't help. However, I did now discover a reliable solution, through `Physics.SyncTransforms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @DMGregory on [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for the suggestion, a call to [`Physics.SyncTransforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) before invoking `Rigidbody.ResetCenterOfMass` fixes the problem:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform SpawnPrefab;
  public Vector3 Scale;

    void Start () {
      var spawn = Instantiate(SpawnPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
      spawn.localScale = Vector3.Scale(spawn.localScale, Scale);
      Physics.SyncTransforms();
      spawn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();
    }
}
```

Evidently this direct modification of the transform scale isn't being automatically passed through to the physics engine, but `Physics.SyncTransforms` lets us manually flush those changes down to PhysX, so that the `ResetCenterOfMass` computation is then based on the correctly scaled transform.